# Нужно создать n объектов одной строкой

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть какой-то случайный класс:

```
class MyClass:
    pass
```

Нужно 1 строкой создать n объектов этого класса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
n = 5
obj_list = [MyClass() for _ in range(n)]
print(obj_list)
```

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы создать `n` объектов:

```
for _ in range(n):
    MyClass()
```

Чтобы `n` разных объектов создать и добавить их в список:

```
L = [MyClass() for _ in range(n)]
```

Чтобы создать список, где один и тот же объект `n` раз повторяется:

```
L = [MyClass()] * n
```

Это более эффективно и можно использовать, если `MyClass()` является неизменяемым объектом в вашей задаче, к примеру, как числа, строки, кортежи в Питоне. Лениво можно генерировать значения, используя [`itertools.repeat(MyClass(), n)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat).

Для простых типов (вроде машинных целых), могут быть ещё более эффективные варианты:

```
In [1]: n = 1000_000

In [2]: %timeit [1] * n
3.27 ms ± 28.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [3]: import array

In [4]: %timeit array.array('Q', [1]) * n
829 µs ± 5.64 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [5]: import numpy

In [6]: %timeit numpy.ones(n, dtype='Q')
730 µs ± 5.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

`[1]*n` в четыре раз медленнее здесь чем `array('Q', [1])*n`. `numpy.ones(n, 'Q')` самый быстрый вариант из представленных.